# Map Clipping in Web View

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-maps-api-3

I'm loading a Google Maps API v3 in a native app using a javascript bridge. I'm getting a gray band on the right edge of my maps page. Anyone know how to get rid of it? I also saw Google's tutorial for loading a map in Webview had the same thing. I'd like the map to appear across the entire screen. I'm using a Droid 2.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?  Link to the Google tutorial?  Show a screenshot?   (The first one is the most important/helpful.)

Comment: I followed the code on this Google tutorial. On the map of the Bay Area given in this example you can see the gray band on the right edge. I also have this on my map: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html